# GeoPandas - blur on the upper north of a map

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

I'm plotting a GeoDataFrame `gdf` with elevation data per gridpoint (filled via shapely.geometry.Point). The dataframe ist filled by a csv-file owning some elevation data statistics:

```
df = pd.read_csv(
    FILE_NAME, delimiter=";")  # , header=None,
gdf = GeoDataFrame(
    df.drop(['lon', 'lat'], axis=1),
    crs={'init': 'epsg:4326'},
    geometry=[Point(xy) for xy in zip(df.lon, df.lat)])
```

`gdf.tail()` shows

```
          pkt   class  ...  gesamtzahl                           geometry
161870  23251  1300.0  ...       24960             POINT (15.7036 47.778)
161881  23252  1600.0  ...       24960  POINT (15.7576 47.77770200000001)
161895  23253  2100.0  ...       24960          POINT (15.8116 47.777302)
161906  23254  1600.0  ...       24960          POINT (15.8656 47.776901)
161912  23255  1000.0  ...       24960          POINT (15.9196 47.776501)
```

The elevation data are stored in column `class`. After some seaborn-styling the data is plotted by

```
cm = sns.color_palette('husl', 8, as_cmap=True)
sns.set_theme(context="talk",
              style="whitegrid"
              )
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.1)
gdf.plot(
    column='class',
    ax=ax,
    cax=cax,
    legend=True,
    cmap=cm,
    )
plt.savefig(r"oro-check.png", dpi=300.)
# plt.show()
```

Both `plt.savefig()` and `plt.show()` give/show me an image, which is blurred in the last lines on the top northern end (see red arrows).
[image: elevation statistics with blur]

I get a similar effect in a different projection.

[image]

How can I plot a sound map?

As the data process is still running live in background, there is another image showing no data issues, as the region blurred before is now fine:

[image]

Comment: what happens if you use a different projection?

Comment: I think this is a data issue.